# Png picture in Excel distorted when exported to pdf

Tags: microsoft-excel, png

When I insert a png picture with transparent background in Excel, it looks good in sheet and print preview, but after save in pdf format, the lines gets distorted.

The problem occours using a pdf printer like CutePDF and Adobe PDF. Using "Save As" works great.

[image]

Comment: How are you exporting to PDF?

Comment: It looks as though the box is getting thicker, and the line underneath looks like what was originally in the excel document. Sounds silly but can you try with some other shapes/stuff?

Comment: @Excellll Print to "CutePDF Writer" and "Adobe PDF". Using "Save As" works great. But I really need to use an printer.

Comment: @JCTechie Its not a shape, its cell borders. It happens with every png transparent image.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit these new details into your question.

Comment: Maybe try this: Have you checked the option in Excel 2010?

Click File > Print > Page setup > Sheet, check the box before: Gridlines.

Also, make sure the box before this is uncheck: Draft quality.
from (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/701051c2-2c00-40cc-961e-f055c94f2d06/placing-picture-in-header-messes-up-gridlines-on-print-job-excel-2010?forum=excel)

Comment: This might help as well https://forums.adobe.com/thread/838461

Comment: @JCTechie Tryed solutions, not work. Tryed Foxit and novaPDF, not work too.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted a lot of time sorting the same, and I finally made it fixed in my VBA code. It needs to be adjusted the height before printing to PDF, so its height is increased by 6%, then printed (at that moment it is fine), and then again decrease the image height back to the original height.

If you are interested in the VBA code I created to automate it, you can have a look to my blog:
https://j4.kopl.pro/news/printing-to-pdf-from-microsoft-excel.html
Available for anyone who needs to sort the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .EPS image in Office and export to PDF to make the exported image clear. The EPS file may be distorted in your Office file, though.

Comment: Please give a good solution

Comment: Tryed EPS, same problem.